# Can Export-Csv be given a max no. of rows to write before continuing with a new CSV? (split file)

Tags: csv, powershell

This script audits a share and creates a CSV detailing the file names found and their file extension information - this is working well.  The problem is the CSV often has more rows than Excel is able to open.  Is there a way to split the file - let's say after x no. of rows create a new CSV file?

```
# changes PowerShell prompt to the directory the script is being executed from

function Get-ScriptDirectory {
    $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
    Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path
}

$ISEScriptPath = Split-Path -Parent $psISE.CurrentFile.Fullpath -EA SilentlyContinue

if ($ISEScriptPath -eq $null) {
    cd $(Get-ScriptDirectory -EA SilentlyContinue)
} else {
    cd $ISEScriptPath
}

# checks for logs directory - if directory does not exist creates it
$Logs = Test-Path "$PWD\Logs"
if (-not $Logs) {
    md "$PWD\Logs"
}

############# Main Script ################

$servers = Get-content .\servers.txt          # servers.txt should be in script location containing list of servers to be audited
$share = "e$"                                 # change this to audit location 

foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $now = get-date -format _HHmm_dd-MM-yyyy

    # User Config
    $report = ("FileExtAudit_"+ $server + "_" + $share + "$now.csv") # Name of the file to write out to.
    $scanFrom = "\\$server\$share" # Script will audit this location and everything below (if it has permissions..)

    gci $scanFrom -recurse | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $False} |
        Select-Object DirectoryName, Name, Extension, Length, LastAccessTime,
            @{l="HSM";e={if( $_.Attributes -match "Compressed"){"True"} else {"False"} }},
            @{l="ACL";e={[string]((Get-Acl $_.FullName).Owner)}} |
        Export-Csv "$PWD\Logs\$report" -NoTypeInformation 
}
```

Comment: Does it need to run on PowerShell 2.0?

Comment: No I have access to PowerShell 3.0 and 4.0 also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Export-Csv` doesn't support splitting the input into several files. You have to implement the logic yourself.

Appending in a loop is arguably not the most elegant way to go about this, but it will work without major changes in your code while still avoiding having to collect results in a variable:

```
$maxRecords = 500  # maximum number of records per CSV
$now = Get-Date

foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Get-ChildItem "\\$server\$share" -Recurse |
        Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
        Select-Object DirectoryName, Name, Extension, Length, LastAccessTime,
            @{l="HSM";e={ if ( $_.Attributes -match "Compressed") {$true} else {$false} }},
            @{l="ACL";e={ (Get-Acl $_.FullName).Owner }} |
        ForEach-Object -Begin {$i = 0} -Process {
            $index  = [int][math]::Floor([int]$i/[int]$maxRecords)
            $report = 'FileExtAudit_{0}_{1}_{2:HHmm_dd-MM-yyyy}_{3:d3}.csv' -f $server, $share, $now, $index
            $_ | Export-Csv "$PWD\Logs\$report" -NoType -Append
            $i++
        }
}
```

Using a `StreamWriter` would be a better option from a performance PoV (not only is it faster in and out of itself, but you also avoid repeatedly closing and re-opening the output file). However, it requires more elaborate handling, and you also need to build the CSV lines yourself.

```
$maxRecords = 500  # maximum number of records per CSV
$now = Get-Date

foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Get-ChildItem "\\$server\$share" -Recurse |
        Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $False } |
        Select-Object DirectoryName, Name, Extension, Length, LastAccessTime,
            @{l="HSM";e={ if ( $_.Attributes -match "Compressed") {$true} else {$false} }},
            @{l="ACL";e={ (Get-Acl $_.FullName).Owner }} |
        ForEach-Object -Begin {$i = 0} -Process {
            if ($i % $maxRecords -eq 0) {
                if ($writer) {
                    $writer.Close()
                    $writer.Dispose()
                }
                $index  = [int][math]::Floor([int]$i/[int]$maxRecords)
                $report = 'FileExtAudit_{0}_{1}_{2:HHmm_dd-MM-yyyy}_{3:d3}.csv' -f $server, $share, $now, $index
                $writer = [IO.StreamWriter]"$PWD\Logs\$report"
                $writer.WriteLine('"DirectoryName","Name","Extension","Length","LastAccessTime","HSM","ACL"')
            }
            $writer.WriteLine(('"{0}","{1}","{2}","{3}","{4}","{5}","{6}"' -f $_.DirectoryName, $_.Name, $_.Extension, $_.Length, $_.LastAccessTime, $_.HSM, $_.ACL))
            $i++
        }

    if ($writer) {
        $writer.Close()
        $writer.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may save your results into a variable and iterate through it using the `.Count` method and split it by yourself. (`select -first X`, or `select -index 1000..1999`, etc.)